# Using MATLAB to find strings of numbers in nominal data

Tags: string, matlab

I have a file of nominal data containing year, month, day, and exceedence. If a day is an exceedence, it is assigned a 1. If it is not an exceedence, it is assigned a 0. I want to find strings of days that are characterized by a 1. The strings have to be a minimum of length 2. Also, since 3 days of 1s also contains a 2-day string of 1s, there has to be at least one day separating a string of 1s for the strings to be separate. In other words, a 2-day string would have to have at least one day between it and another string of 1s for it to be considered a 2-day string. This same rule would have to follow for all strings of any length. I'm not sure how to set this up...Here's a look at the code I have so far:

```
load file_name.txt
year=file_name(:,1);
month=file_name(:,2);
day=file_name(:,3);
exceedence=file_name(:,4);

for i=1:61
    yr=i+1950;
    for j=7:8
        for k=1:31
            [yr j k];
            ga=find(year==yr&month==j&day==k&exceedence);
            x=exceedence(ga);
```

I don't have to worry about leap years because I'm only using two months (July and August). At the end of the day, I want a file containing the year for the first column, and the total number of strings of 1s of a given length for the subsequent columns. In other words, I want to know how many times there were 2-day strings of ones, 3-day strings of ones, 4-day strings of ones, and so forth in a given year. I hope this makes sense!

Thanks,

Zach

Comment: Any advice at all would be much appreciated!

Comment: Couple things: 1) Can you please post some sample data from `file_name.txt`? 2) What exactly is the problem you're having? Why doesn't your code work? 3) You are using the word "string" in your question, and I think you mean "series" or "in a row". "String", w.r.t. programming languages, has a very specific meaning (i.e. a series of characters), which is distinct from how you're using "string" in your question. If I'm off base, just let me know!

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious how this code gets your sequences of ones and zeros to start with.  I am assuming that is not the hard part,  so once you have that sequence, here is what I would do.

if x is your sequence, first prepend and append zeros

```
x = [0,x,0]
```

Then take the diff to find the transitions

```
transitions = diff(x)
upTransitions = find(transitions > 0)
downTransitions = find(transitions < 0)

nDays = downTransitions - upTransitions + 1;
```

You can then take a histogram

```
hist(nDays)
```

If you want to customize the histogram bins, just do `help hist` to see the options.